# A conondrum with unity's coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates, transform

i wanted to ask for help regarding unity's coordination system. I have an image in my canvas and i want to make a smooth transition when i do something. I made a code that when the game start's it will go to the -700 0 coordinates and once i pressed on a thing, it will go to 0, 0 to show up on canvas, but instead it decides to go to -1680 -540 coordinates. Can someone explain why does this happen?

Here's some code:

```
    private void Start()
    {
        infoMenu.position = new Vector2(-700, 0);
        foreach (ClickableCountries unit in clickableCountries)
            unit.MouseDown += OnClickableObjectMouseDown;
    }

    private void OnClickableObjectMouseDown(ClickableCountries unit)
    {
        Debug.Log("pressed");
        infoMenu.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0 * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
    }
```

Comment: quick question... isn't `0 * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f` always `0`?

Comment: Im pretty sure that its coordinates * the speed theyre going to go there

Comment: @HoxhaAlban absolutely, @Paul nope .. you are multiplying a value by `0` so it will always be `0`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer you should just use rect transform's anchored position and it places it into its exact coordinates

```
    private void Start()
    {
        infoMenu.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-700, 0 * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
        foreach (ClickableCountries unit in clickableCountries)
            unit.MouseDown += OnClickableObjectMouseDown;
    }

    private void OnClickableObjectMouseDown(ClickableCountries unit)
    {
        Debug.Log("pressed");
        //infoMenu.transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0 * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
        infoMenu.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 0 * Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
    }
```

Comment: You are still multiplying by `0` though